# How to use non camera YUV stream as input to google mediapipe execution pipline graph?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, mediapipe

I am working on [Mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe) real time [Hand tracking](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/tree/master/mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu) application in for android. Provided demo is using Camera input from SurfaceTexture's `ExternalOES` I want to use network stream which is coming from webrtc. Network stream is in YUV_I420 format so I am converting it into RGB and creating RGB packet using [AndroidPacketCreator](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/java/com/google/mediapipe/framework/AndroidPacketCreator.java) like this.

```java
Packet imagePacket = packetCreator.createRgbaImageFrame(yuv_converted_bimap);
```

and then passing it to mediapipe graph in `FrameProcessor` class

```java
mediapipeGraph.addConsumablePacketToInputStream(
          videoInputStream, imagePacket, custom_timestamp);
```

With this way everything is working fine only performance is degrading i.e with camera stream if it is able process 4-5 FPS then with this YUV to RGB approach it is processing only 2-3 FPS. I want to find another approach where I can use YUV stream directly to send mediapipe graph. I did some research but could not found anything. Anyone has any Idea how to do that?

Comment: Cool, I want to do the same, do you have a repository where I can follow you ? I'm interested how exactly you provide the network video stream